# What needs to be added to this google script to mark the emails as read

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-apps, google-email-settings-api

I'm looking to see how to mark the messages read after executing this script. I've read through [Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#markMessageRead(GmailMessage)), but I am too much of a novice to know what to do.

This script would be successful for me if it pulled the email data into google sheets based on the search criteria and then marked those messages as read. Currently, it will only pull the emails into google sheets.

Thank you for your time.

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:aggieworks is:unread to:me subject:*WO:*";

// Credit: https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708

function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
                .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
            ]);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}

function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the function works as you have it. This should mark the messages as read.

```
function getEmails_(q) 
{
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) 
        {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
                .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')]);
            msgs[j].markRead();   
        }
    }
    return emails;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper. It works. However, I do have an error.

TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 21, file "GetEmailRecieved") 3

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code that produces the error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 21,
>   file "GetEmailRecieved")

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:aggieworks is:unread";

// Credit: https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708


function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
                .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
            ]);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}

function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }
}

function getEmails_(q) 
{
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) 
        {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
                .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')]);
            msgs[j].markRead();   
        }
    }
    return emails;
}
```

Comment: Something appears to be wrong with array2d or array2d[0].

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the length error is that `array2d` is zero. The `appendData_`  function fails.

The `array2d` contents need to be evaluated before the `appendData_` function is executed in an `if()` statement.

I do not know yet how that will look

Comment: From the Help, "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." The answer might be better as a comment.